# How can I search for a word in my DB and replace it with its synonym

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have written the following code but I get an exception :

```
for (int i = 0; i < wsize1 - 1;)
{
    string w = words1[i];

    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from synreplace where word="+words1[i], myConnection);

    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    if (myReader["syn"].ToString() != null)
    {
        words1[i] = myReader["syn"].ToString();
    }

    i++;
}
```

The exception is :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid column name 'wer'.

`'wer'` is the string in words1[i]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to surround the word value in single quotes to fix your syntax error:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from synreplace where word='"+words1[i]+"'", myConnection);
```

(or use parameters)

This does the selection.  The question title is about replacing a value, though.

Comment: `new SqlCommand("update synreplace set word = replace(word, 'theword', 'synonym') where word = '" + words1[i] + "'", myConnection);`

Comment: i still have this exception :
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: For an update, I think you want `ExecuteNonQuery()` not `ExecuteReader()`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff but for reading the extracted information what should i do ? (if i use ExecuteNonQuery() instead)

Comment: @ilia7 . . . Run a select query afterwards to look at the values.